# Qt::Pixmap in Qwidget doesn't show up in MainWindow

Tags: qt, qwidget, qpixmap

Here is another newbie to Qt.

What I need to do is to have a scrollable Area in the center of MainWindow, which displays images, and allows user to paint on the image.

Since I cannot add a QPixmap directly to a scrollable Area, I tried to create a subclass of QWidget, like below:

```
class Canvas: public QWidget
{
public:
    Canvas(){
    image = new QPixmap(480,320);
    image->fill(Qt::red);
    }
    QPixmap *image;
};
```

Then I declared Canvas *c in the header file.

In the implementation, I wrote:

```
  canvas = new Canvas;
  setCentralWidget(canvas);
```

However, apparently this does not help to show up the QPixmap. I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to subclass QWidget for this. QPixmap is not a widget, so it is not shown anywhere. You need to add your pixmap to some widget, this will work:

in header:

```
QLabel* imageLabel;
```

in cpp:

```
imageLabel = new QLabel(this);
QPixmap image(480,320);
image.fill(Qt::red);
imageLabel->setPixmap(image);
setCentralWidget(imageLabel);
```

Comment: The problem is that, if I do it this way, can I paint on the QLabel? By painting on the qlabel, does it directly changing the corresponding Pixmap?

Comment: What if I want continuously changing the Pixmap? So everytime I have to call imageLabel->setPixmap() function?

Comment: No, in that case I think it is better not to use QLabel. I mean, yes, you can call imageLabel->setPixmap() everytime, but it will affect performance a lot if you do that continuously. Take a look at QGraphicsScene, QImage, QGraphicsView...